# moving backwards into a safety zone in the game Sorry

Tags: sorry

can a player move *backwards* into *their safety zone* in the game of Sorry?

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot. From the [rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/sorry.pdf), under the "Safety Zone" section:

> **No pawn may enter its SAFETY ZONE by a backward move**; however, a pawn may move backward out of its SAFETY ZONE and on subsequent turns move back into the ZONE as cards permit.

Answer (score -2):

A pawn actually can move into the safety zone on a backwards move. From the Moving Backward section:
"If you have moved a pawn backward at least 2 spaces from your start space, you may, on a subsequent turn, move into your safety zone (on a backwards move)."

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for your answer! Can you provide a link to the rules you're looking at? The [rules referenced by GendoIkari's answer](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Sorry.PDF) do not agree with your quote.

Comment: This rule is talking about moving backwards past your starting place, and then later moving forwards into your safety zone without having gone all the way around the board. The "(on a backwards move)" part in your quote isn't in the rules.